# Error in Finding graphallshortestpaths in a matrix

Tags: matlab, shortest-path

I have a matrix say A=[2 1;3 1;4 1;5 1;1 2;3 2;4 2;1 3;2 3;5 3;1 4;2 4;5 4;1 5;3 5;4 5];
I want to find the graphallshortestpaths in this network.

I have gone through this link http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/graphallshortestpaths.html

> > adj_sparse = sparse(test);
> >
> > distances = graphallshortestpaths(adj_sparse);
> >     According to the example , this should return me a matrix of the shortest path.
> >     however i am getting an error as

```
Error using graphalgs Sparse array should have same number of rows and columns.

Error in graphallshortestpaths (line 85)
    dist = graphalgs('all',debug_level,directed,G);
```

The Solution given below by @rayryeng works, but only for relatively lesser nodes.

---

I am able to run this algorithm and get results for some files which are relatively small. but while running this algorithm for larger file, I encountered some "**memory running out**" problem when i compute a larger file ,say more than 30000 node. (I have a very high config PC though :) ) I heard about a package in Python called **igraph** which gives the result very fast!. Do we have any similar algorithm in **matlab** that has been optimized to compute for very large nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're not creating the sparse matrix properly.  You are taking the matrix `A` and converting it into a sparse matrix.  I suspect that `A` is a connectivity matrix where a row denotes an edge between the two nodes.  I'm also going to assume that the weights connected to each of your nodes is equal to 1.  As such, you need to do this:

```
A=[2 1;3 1;4 1;5 1;1 2;3 2;4 2;1 3;2 3;5 3;1 4;2 4;5 4;1 5;3 5;4 5];
G = sparse(A(:,1), A(:,2), 1);
graphallshortestpaths(G)
```

Note that you need to specify the row locations of the sparse matrix to be the first column of `A`, while the column locations of your sparse matrix is the second column of `A`.  With the above, I get:

```
ans =

 0     1     1     1     1
 1     0     1     1     2
 1     1     0     2     1
 1     1     2     0     1
 1     2     1     1     0
```

Comment: Spot on !! Thanks. However, can you point me to the resource
 G = sparse(A(:,1), A(:,2), 1);

Comment: @BoyLittUp - You're welcome!  As for knowing how to structure `sparse`, just look at the documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html.  Look at the fourth style of calling `sparse`: `S = sparse(i,j,s);`.  `i` and `j` are the row and column locations of where the matrix is non-zero, and `s` can either be a vector of elements for each corresponding row-column pair, or you can specify a **single** number where each element in your matrix take this number.  You'll get to a point where you don't need the documentation as you start using these functions often!